# Match a table of regular expressions

Tags: regex, r

I have a list of occupations and want to match them to larger categories of occupations. To do this, I have a table containing a list of patterns and the matching category of occupation. For example,

```
REGEX                               SuperCategory
cleaner                             Cleaners
(police)|(paramedic)|(emergency)    Emergency services
(manager)|(director)|(executive)    Management

structure(list(REGEX = c("cleaner", "(police)|(paramedic)|(emergency)"
), SuperCategory = c("Cleaners", NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .Names = c("REGEX", "SuperCategory"
))
```

I would like to create a new column in another data frame which is the elements of SuperCategory where there is a match the REGEX pattern for the corresponding row.

What I'm doing now is a series of `ifelse` statements combined with `grepl`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(SuperOccupation = ifelse(grepl(regex_decoder$REGEX[1], Occupation1, ignore.case=TRUE), 
                                  regex_decoder$SuperCategory[1],
                                  ifelse(grepl(regex_decoder$REGEX[2], 
                                               Occupation1, 
                                               ignore.case=TRUE), 
                                         regex_decoder$SuperCategory[2], 
                                         ifelse(grepl(regex_decoder$REGEX[3],
                                                      Occupation1,
                                                      ignore.case=TRUE),
                                                regex_decoder$SuperCategory[3],
                                                NA_character_))))
```

But I would have to continue nesting for the length of my table. Is there a way to "join" by regular expressions?

Comment: Why not just replace your values or create a new column with the `SuperCategory` and then aggregate?

Comment: Not sure what you mean Prolix

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. The easiest might be to duplicate your column and then use `str_replace` from the package `stringr`.

Comment: for simple fixes with regexps you can vectorize them like `Vectorize(grepl)(df$REGEX, df$SuperCategory, ignore.case=TRUE)`.  But, if you need efficiency, those `stringr` and `stringi` functions are already vectorized properly.  This is equivalent to using `mapply(grepl(...), column1, column2)`